Difference between connecting an inductive load to VM or GND?
To start off, low-side, high-side, half-bridge, and H-bridge topologies for driving motors / inductive loads is a relatively new topic for me so I do not have a lot of insight into these designs.
I've been seeing variations, with respect to a half-bridge configuration, of where the load is actually connected. Specifically, with the half-bridge IC I have selected, the load is depicted to be between VM and the output.


As far as I understand, they both essentially do the same thing, but the logic for controlling the HS/LS of the driver would be flipped depending on if the load is connected between the output and GND vs. the output and VM. Am I correct in my understanding?
I just want to ensure that I'm not making any glaring mistakes by using the configuration on the left.
Thanks in advance.

Not a real answer but it kind of depends on the specific chip and implementation. Looking at the block diagram of the one you linked, I would have said that current sensing is only available with low-side switching but apparently not according to figs 7-5 through 7-8. Paragraph 2 of this app note (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvae59a/slvae59a.pdf) states that the configuration choice affects which faults (short to supply or short to ground) are protected against in each configuration but that seems a minor point to me.
